# Lubuntu loop before login screen

Tags: gnome, lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu as text mode, then I installed gnome manually.

After reboot, It showed a mouse and then disappeared. Loop and loop.....

--Edit--
Add some info:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 28
model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x218
cpu MHz     : 875.106
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3191.79
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 28
model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x218
cpu MHz     : 849.846
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3191.79
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

---

```
$ hwinfo --short
cpu:                                                            
                       Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz, 1530 MHz
                       Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz, 1571 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/event4    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
monitor:
                       CPT LCD Monitor
graphics card:
                       Intel 945 GME
                       Intel Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
sound:
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
storage:
                       Intel 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode]
network:
  enp3s0               Marvell 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
  wlp2s0               Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
network interface:
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  enp3s0               Ethernet network interface
  wlp2s0               Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             FUJITSU MHZ2160B
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
  /dev/sda2            Partition
  /dev/sda3            Partition
  /dev/sda5            Partition
  /dev/sda6            Partition
  /dev/sda7            Partition
usb controller:
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
                       Intel Mobile 945GSE Express Memory Controller Hub
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1
                       Intel 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Broadcom BCM2045 Bluetooth
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       Intel NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller
                       Unclassified device
                       Unclassified device
                       Unclassified device
                       Unclassified device
                       Unclassified device
                       Unclassified device
                       Unclassified device
                       Z-Star Microelectronics Namuga 1.3M Webcam
```

Comment: Please provide release details (Lubuntu could mean LXDE (legacy) or LXQt (modern) depending on release).  And do you mean by text mode the alternate installer (ie. your machine has <=768MB of ram?)

Comment: @guiverc 
First, my lubuntu is LXDE, and I have 1 GB RAM.

But I scare that my RAM is too small, so I used the alternate installer.

I choose the text mode at the F4 list.

Comment: On 1gb of RAM I wouldn't try using GNOME; but I still don't know your release.  How did you install gnome (`ubuntu-desktop` or something else?  though release details are required as how installed varies on release)  Did you switch to `gdm3` (the default for GNOME or `ubuntu-desktop` on 18.04) or keep the Lubuntu default?  I've tested Lubuntu on 1gb laptops, but not GNOME/gdm3 on 1gb boxes.

Comment: I installed <code> gnome </code> , not <code> ubuntu-desktop </code>

Comment: I don't know your release, nor what you installed (`ubuntu-desktop` will install the full GNOME desktop on Lubuntu 18.04 LTS; did you install everything? or what did you actually install; plus on what release)

Comment: oh no, I just installed gnome, no ubuntu-desktop!

Comment: I cant access the computer via ssh or change tty.

Comment: @guiverc I can't access my computer's command line ( because I can't switch tty and login via ssh ), so how can I install ubuntu-desktop now?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help, I still don't know your release details

Comment: did you mean this? `lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386`

Answer (score 2):

Many users encounter hardware compatibility problems, but that can be resolved in different ways.

(*My answer will not necessarily be your solution, I will simply try to help you by giving you the answer to my problem.*)

You will sometimes only need to set some kernel parameters for ubuntu to boot or work properly, and it is with this solution that I will try to help you.

One of the most common issues, and this is the one that has helped me is **nomodeset** which is needed for some graphic cards for work proprely.

Try adding a nomodeset parameter to your Ubuntu system using GRUB 2.

As the system starts to boot repeated tap the Esc key in order to force the "GNU GRUB" menu to appear. For BIOS-mode (not UEFI-mode) booting a SHIFT key can be held down continuously until the menu appears. The "GNU GRUB" menu will look something like [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=grub2_default_menu.png).

Once the "GNU GRUB" menu appears highlight the desired entry and press the e key to enter edit mode. The edit mode screen will look something like [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=grub2_menu_editing.png).

Just after the words :

> quiet splash

add the word :

> nomodeset

After this, press Ctrl+X to boot the system using the parameters you've added.

*(Note: The parameter(s) you've added to the linux line are only temporary: They will affect this boot session, but once you restart the system they will no longer be in effect, if you want use permanently, follow [this full tutorial.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters))*

If it still does not work, I invite you to try with different options such as :

> acpi=off

or

> acpi_osi

or

> noapic

or

> nolapic

*I hope this solves your problem, or at least that I could help other people who will have this problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Your machine doesn't meet the minimum specifications for GNOME desktop, so problems are expected.

Requirements for GNOME are

> Ubuntu Desktop Edition
>
> - 2 GHz dual core processor
> - 4 GiB RAM (system memory)
> - 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
> - VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> - 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB

Your graphics uses your main memory; so not only do you not have 4GB of RAM, but you're using 256MB of your RAM for your video card, leaving only 768MB of RAM.

To me, the failure is your machine not meeting minimum specifications for Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME desktop.

source : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

*The only N270 atom I have is in an old eeepc, and I've never tried running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME on it, nor would I try.   I would backout all GNOME desktop packages you have installed, and use LXDE.  Use your `history` (ie. command history if you added packages via command), or `apt` logs found in `/var/log/apt/history.log` to put your system back where it was, if you don't have ready backups to restore*.

My 2c